# Unitary equivalence to permutation matrix

Tags: matrices, permutations, roots-of-unity, unitary-matrices, permutation-matrices

I would like to find a check whether a given matrix is unitarily equivalent to a permutation matrix. I split this question into two parts below. I expect the solution will use the second part, but if not that's fine.

${\bf(1)}$ Let $M$ be a unitary matrix. How can I check if there exists a unitary $U$ such that $U M U^\dagger = P$ is a permutation matrix?

I know that a permutation matrix has eigenvalues that form complete sets of roots of unity. The question then boils down to.

${\bf(2)}$ Given a set of complex numbers on the unit circle $S = \{z_1,z_2,z_3,\ldots\}$, is there a simple test to check if this contains complete sets of roots of unity. In other words, check that $S= S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots$, where $S_i = \{e^{2\pi i \frac{n}{q}} | n \in \{0,\ldots,q-1\} \}$, for $q\in \mathbb{N}$.

**Examples**
$\{1,1,1,-1\} = \{1\} \cup \{1\} \cup \{1,-1\}$ and so this does have complete sets of roots of unity.
$\{1,i,-i,1\}$ does not contain complete sets of roots of unity.

Comment: If the charactertic polynomial $p(x) = \det(xI - M)$ has (real) integer coefficients, then we can guarantee that $M$ has eigenvalues that can be grouped into complete sets of roots of unity and possibly a set of non-matching $-1$'s.

Comment: Is that easy to prove? It's not immediately clear to me. Also does it work the other way? That if they are not all integer then they are not sets of roots of unity?

Comment: Yes it's easy to prove and yes it works the other way. If I get the chance I'll write an answer

Comment: On second thought, I'm wrong about my earlier statement; it only works "the other way".  For instance, no permutation matrix has characteristic polynomial $x^2 \pm x + 1$, but these have roots of magnitude $1$ not equal to $-1$.

Comment: Another observation is that if $M$ is similar to a permutation matrix, then it must satisfy $M^k = I$ for some $k$.

Comment: Thanks, but again that is a property that is easily satisfied by non-permutation matrices.

Comment: I derived an algorithm focusing on $\text{trace}\big(M^k\big)$ for $k\in\{1,2,..,n\}$.  There may be a loose end or two, but the underlying ideas are so simple I don't think it has any fatal weaknesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Main ideas**
i.)  Unitary matrices (including permutation matrices as a special case) are normal, so they are unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix $D$, which is itself unitary.  Thus to test whether we can have $UMU^* = P$, with given $M$ and some $\text{n x n}$ Permutation matrix $P$ it suffices to check that there is some (unitary) diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ that they could both be similar to.  Since diagonalizability is guaranteed, it suffices to check some algebraic invariant like the characteristic polynomial.

ii.)  With $M = QDQ^*$ and $P= V\Lambda V^*$ The algebraic invariant of interest is in fact the trace.  I.e. examine $\text{trace}\big(M^k\big)= \text{trace}\big(D^k\big)$ for $k\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ and checking whether it could be equal to  $\text{trace}\big(P^k\big) = \text{trace}\big(\Lambda^k\big)$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal and has the constraint that it only has complete sets of $r_i$th roots of unity, with each $r_i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$. The trace is of interest since it counts closed walks on graphs and any permutation matrix $P$ *is* an adjacency matrix for a graph.  Of course $P$, if it exists, may be written in a particularly simple form-- counting the number of eigenvalues of 1 tells us how many communicating classes it has (up to graph isomorphism this should be thought of as disjoint blocked cyclic permutation submatrices);  this result follows e.g. from Perron-Frobenius Theory.  We can even do better and construct a simple $P$ here, if it exists, by paying attention to the specific rth roots of unity and associated 'multiplicities'.  The algorithm below actually gives a way to construct a 'nice' Permutation matrix $P$ that is similar to $M$ (and fails if some similarity is not possible).

Part (2) of the OP is a good question in that it maps question (1) down to a simpler problem, but implies the result for (1).  I give an algorithmic solution to (2), below.  Once that is understood, one can re-run the below algorithm verbatim, except compute $\text{trace}\big(M^k \big)$ and $\text{trace}\big(M^k - \Lambda^k\big)$ instead of $\text{trace}\big(D^k\big)$ and $\text{trace}\big(D^k - \Lambda^k\big)$.

For avoidance of doubt for (2), instead of a "set" I interpret this as a "multi-set" $S$ and $\big \vert S\big \vert = n$.  With part 1 in mind this means we are interested solely in finding complete sets of $r_i$th roots of unity for $r_i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$.

*The below algorithm assumes we are working with exact precision (or symbolically).  Issues surrounding round-off for arbitrarily large matrices... are way outside the scope.*

---

**algorithm for (2) which implies (1)**
Suppose that your multiset of eigenvalues / numbers on the unit circle correspond to a Permutation matrix.  Place them in diagonal matrix $D$ and focus on taking the trace for powers of $D$.  Also construct n x n diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ where $\lambda_i = 0$ for $i\in\{1,2,..,n\}$ at initialization (i.e. it is initialized to be the zero matrix).

Now compute $\text{trace}\big(D\big) = \alpha$.  If $\alpha =0$ proceed to next step.  If $\alpha$ is not a natural number you can reject the hypothesis that $D$ is similar to a permutation matrix, and the algorithm terminates. If $\alpha\gt 0$ (i.e. $\alpha$ is a positive integer), then set the first available $\alpha$ components on the diagonal of $\Lambda$ equal to one, i.e. $\lambda_i :=1$ for $i\in\{1,2,...,\alpha\}$, and now proceed to the next step.

Compute
$\text{trace}\big(D^k - \Lambda^k\big) = \text{trace}\big(D^k\big) - \text{trace}\big(\Lambda^k\big)$
for $k=2,3,...,n$.
It should be zero or a positive integer throughout -- if you see anything else, the algorithm terminates and we  reject the eigenvalues as belonging to any $\text{n x n}$ permutation matrix.  (This is essentially an assert line in a for loop.)

As soon as you see some positive integer, you want to 'nullify it'.  (The idea to 'nullify' comes from the idea of reducibility of a graph in Perron Frobenius theory.)  Put differently, we have $\text{trace}\big(D^1 - \Lambda^1\big)=0$ and we want to replicate this behavior for higher powers.

Suppose e.g. $\text{trace}\big(D^2-\Lambda^2\big)=5$.  This implies $5$ 2nd roots of unity that did not 'show up' in $\text{trace}\big(D^1\big)$ -- this is a problem... because if they are complete sets we need $\text{5%2} =0$.  So if  $\text{trace}\big(D^2- \Lambda^2\big)=\alpha$ and $\alpha \text{% 2} \neq 0$ the algorithm terminates and we reject the eigenvalues as being associated with any $\text{n x n}$ permutation matrix $P$.  Otherwise if $\alpha \text{% 2} = 0$ and $\alpha$ is a positive integer, proceed to 'nullify' these roots of unity.  Say e.g. $\alpha = 6$.  Then place 3 complete sets of 2nd roots of unity, in 3 contiguous 'diagonal blocks' in the the next available slots of $\Lambda$ (i.e. first remaining zeros on the diagonal) .

Now proceed to compute $\text{trace}\big(D^3-\Lambda^3\big)$ and repeat the above process, then $\text{trace}\big(D^4-\Lambda^4\big)$ and repeat above process, then $\text{trace}\big(D^5-\Lambda^5\big)$, and so on.

After this has been done all the way up to and including $k=n$ without raising an error, then we know
$\text{trace}\big(D^k-\Lambda^k\big) = 0 \longrightarrow \text{trace}\big(D^k\big) = \text{trace}\big(\Lambda^k\big)$
for $k \in\{1,2,...,n\}$
By Newton's Identities, $D$ has the same characteristic polynomial (and hence eigenvalues) as $\Lambda$.  I.e. up to graph isomorphism $D = \Lambda$.

The underlying idea here is that sums of sets of complete $r_i$th roots of unity ($r_i \geq 2)$ telescope for powers less than $r_i$ so each time we append new $r_i$th roots of unity to $\Lambda$ we don't impact the $\text{trace}\big(\Lambda^k\big)$ for $k\in \{1,2,...,r_i-1\}$, and this allows us to exploit a kind of optimal substructure.

**closing ideas**:
Newton's Identities implies $\big \vert\det\big(\Lambda \big )\big \vert  = \big \vert\det\big(D\big )\big \vert = 1$ -- so if the algorithm made it through $k=n$ without raising an error, then $\Lambda$ has no zeros on its diagonal.  Furthermore, we constructed all the non-zero diagonal components of $\Lambda$ to come in diagonal 'blocks' $r_i$ at a time corresponding to complete sets of $r_i$th roots of unity.  Thus $\Lambda$ can be separated into $m$ distinct complete sets of $r_i$ roots of unity for $r_i \in \{1,2...,n\}$ for $i\in\{1,2,....,m\}$ where $m$ is the number of 1's in $\Lambda$ -- and e.g. Perron Frobenius Theory tells us the associated permutation matrix $P$ has $m$ distinct communicating classes, each of size $r_i$.

This motivates a different approach to the algorithm -- rather than constructing $\Lambda$ as we go, we could construct a particularly nice $P$ as the algorithm proceeds.  e.g. if at step one we had $\alpha = 5$, then the next step had $\alpha = 4$, and then $\alpha = 3$, then after 3 iterations we'd have a candidate $P= \begin{bmatrix}
 I_{5} &  \mathbf 0 &  \mathbf 0& \mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0 &  \cdots &  \mathbf 0 \\ 
\mathbf 0&  C^{(2)} &  \mathbf 0& \mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0 &  \cdots &   \mathbf 0 \\ 
 \mathbf 0&   \mathbf 0&    C^{(2)}&\mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0 &  \cdots  &  \mathbf 0 \\ 
 \mathbf 0&   \mathbf 0& \mathbf 0&   C^{(3)} &  \mathbf 0 &\cdots  &  \mathbf 0 \\ 
 \mathbf 0&   \mathbf 0&   \mathbf 0& \mathbf 0& \mathbf 0 &  \cdots &  \mathbf 0 \\ 
 \vdots&   \vdots&   \vdots& \vdots& \vdots &  \ddots &  \vdots \\ 
 \mathbf 0&   \mathbf 0 &  \mathbf 0& \mathbf 0& \mathbf 0 &   \cdots&  \mathbf 0
\end{bmatrix}$

where $C^{(j)}$ is the $\text{j x j}$ 'cyclic permutation matrix' which is also the Companion matrix associated with the polynomial $x^j -1$.  Of course, re-visiting this entire process, it becomes clear that we never needed the diagonal matrix $D$ that our unitary matrix $M$ is similar to -- we could have simply worked with traces of powers of $M$.