# Two permutation matrices represent conjugate permutations iff they have same characteristic polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, characteristic-polynomial, permutation-matrices

I was told that

> Two permutation matrices represent conjugate permutations iff they have same characteristic polynomial (where the conjugacy is considered only in $S_{n}$).

The first implication is clear to me i.e. permutation matrices representing conjugate permutations, being similar matrices, have same characteristic polynomial.
But, I do not understand why is it necessary that if two permutation matrices have same characteristic polynomial they should represent conjugate permutation? I was told to see newton's identities. But I do not see anything relating characteristic polynomial with permutation matrices in them.

Anyhow, I did it and I have written answer. But, I would really like to know a whether there exists a proof that uses newtons identities or algaebraic manipulations.

Comment: What is the conjugate of a permutation matrix?

Comment: Still not completely familiar with the terminology; does this mean applying both of them yields the identity (they are inverses)?

Comment: @paulinho No. In language of linear algaebra-- Two matrices $P$ and $Q$  represent conjugate permutations if there is some permutation matrix $R$ such that $RQR^{-1} = P$.In language of group theory-- Two permutations $σ,σ′ ∈ S_{n}$ are conjugate if exists $τ$∈$S_{n}$ such that: $σ′ = τστ^{−1}$

Comment: The difficulty lies in that it is not true in general.  Conjugacy is relative to the group, but characteristic polynomials aren't. $(123)$ and $(132)$ have the same characteristic polynomial, but they are not conjugate in $A_3$.

Comment: But that is true only for $S_n$. In the link you provide, the answer by Gerry Myerson explains it well.

Comment: This is "Brauer's permutation lemma", as in [L. G. Kovács, *The permutation lemma of Richard Brauer*](https://sci-hub.tw/https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/14.2.127). (The proof given by Kovács relies on the [determinant of the Smith matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299652/let-the-matrix-a-a-ij-n%c3%97n-be-defined-by-a-ij-gcdi-j-how-prove-t).)

Comment: I like the persistence here.  The linkage I had in mind when I made that comment is $\text{same cycle structure} \longrightarrow \text{same number of closed walks on any iteration}\longrightarrow \text{same charpoly}$ and  $\text{same charpoly} \longrightarrow \text{same number closed walks}\longrightarrow \text{same cycle structure} $, where the number of closed walks on iteration k is given by $\text{trace}\big(P^k\big)$; Newton's Identities links trace to charpoly.  A related algorithmic approach: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567851/unitary-equivalence-to-permutation-matrix/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ (listed with algebraic multiplicity), then $A^k$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1^k,\dots,\lambda_n^k$, and so $\operatorname{tr}(A^k)=\sum_i\lambda_i^k.$  By Newton's identities, $\sum_i\lambda_i^k$ can be expressed in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials in the $\lambda_i$, which are just (up to sign) the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

The upshot is that if $A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic polynomial, then $\operatorname{tr}(A^k)=\operatorname{tr}(B^k)$ for all $k$.  Now if $A$ is a permutation matrix corresponding to a permutation $\pi$, then $\operatorname{tr}(A^k)$ is just the number of fixed points of $\pi^k$.  So, it suffices to show that if $\pi,\rho\in S_n$ are such that $\pi^k$ and $\rho^k$ have the same number of fixed points for each $k$, then $\pi$ and $\rho$ have the same cycle structure.  To show this, let $a_k$ be the number of $k$-cycles in $\pi$ and let $b_k$ be the number of $k$-cycles in $\rho$.  Note then that the number of fixed points of $\pi^k$ is $\sum_{d\mid k}da_d$ and the number of fixed points of $\rho^k$ is $\sum_{d\mid k}db_d$.  We know these are equal, and using strong induction on $k$ we may assume that $a_d=b_d$ for every proper divisor $d$ of $k$.  It follows that $ka_k=kb_k$ and thus $a_k=b_k$.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but how did you reach the conclusion that the number of fixed points in $\pi^{k}$ is $\sum_{d|k}da_{d}$?

Comment: A point is fixed by $\pi^k$ iff it is part of a $d$-cycle for some $d$ dividing $k$.

Answer (score 6):

We'll first prove that the characteristic polynomial of a permutation matrix representing a permutation $\pi\in S_{n}$ having the cycle structure $1^{c_{1}}2^{c_{2}}...n^{c_{n}}$ is of the form $\prod_{j=1}^{n}(x^{j}-1)^{c_{j}}$.

The eigenvalues of any permutation matrix representing the cycle structure $1^{c_{1}}2^{c_{2}}...n^{c_{n}}$ are $i_{th}$ roots of unity counted with multiplicities $c_{i}$ (where i represents the cycle lengths), which is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168674/how-to-find-the-eigenvalues-of-permutation-matrices?noredirect=1&lq=1).  As we know that Eigenvalues are the roots of characteristic polynomial, the polynomial corresponding to these eigenvalues is clearly  $\prod_{j=1}^{n}(x^{j}-1)^{c_{j}}$.

We'll prove that such representation is unique. Before that let's state a fact we'll use

> The nth root of unity $\alpha = cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})+isin(\frac{2\pi}{n})$ does not satisfy $x^{k}-1 = 0$ for $0\lt k\lt n$. But for $k\gt n$ it satisfies $x^{k}-1 = 0$ for $k=nt$ where $t\in \Bbb N$.

Coming to the proof, Let $XP_{1}$ and $XP_{2}$ both have same roots of unity counted with multiplicities. But $XP_{1}$ and $XP_{2}$ differ in their representation i.e.
They are like
$$XP_{1} = \prod_{j=1}^{n}(x^{j}-1)^{c_{j}}, XP_{2} = \prod_{j=1}^{n}(x^{j}-1)^{d_{j}}$$ Let $j_{1}$ be the greatest $j$ such that  $c_{j}\neq d_{j}$. As per our assumption and the fact we stated above, the occurence of the $j_{1}$ root of unity  $\alpha = cos(\frac{2\pi}{j_{1}})+isin(\frac{2\pi}{j_{1}})$ in $XP_{1}$ and $XP_{2}$
$1$. Due to $(x^{j}-1)^{c_{j}}$ for $j\gt j_{1}$ is same in both.
$2$. Due to $(x^{j}-1)^{c_{j}}$ for $j\lt j_{1}$ is zero.
$3$. Due to $(x^{j}-1)^{c_{j}}$ for $j=j_{1}$ viz $c_{j_{1}}$,$d_{j_{1}}$ is different.

But it means multiplicities of $\alpha$ are different in $XP_{1}$ and $XP_{2}$. We reach a contradiction. Hence $c_{j} = d_{j} \space \forall j\in \Bbb N$

Now if two permutation matrices have the same characteristic polynomial they must have the same cycle type and hence they must represent conjugate permutations in $S_{n}$.

Comment: Can you reference or show why the characteristic polynomial looks like that?

Comment: @Phicar: Separate cycles act on mutually orthogonal invariant subspaces, therefore the characteristic polynomial decomposes to the product of cycle polynomials. The characteristic polynomial for a single cycle is easily calculated directly.

Comment: I see, thanks both!

Comment: There is a gap in this argument: how do you know that the numbers $c_j$ are uniquely determined by the product $\prod_{j=1}^{n}(x^{j}-1)^{c_{j}}$?

Comment: @EricWofsey Can you come up with a counterexample?

Comment: The statement is correct, I'm just saying it takes more work to have a complete proof.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks! I have filled the gap now.